# ¿Como guardar en un arreglo datos recibidos por bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, array, bluetooth, guardar

mi duda es la siguiente: Estoy haciendo un programa en android que recibe 3 datos de un dispositivo bluetooth.

La cosa es que me aparece escrito como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Así se muestran los datos]

como se nota, es en usa sola cadena; y ya lo dividí para que estén en 3 cadenas diferentes utilizando el siguiente método:

```
 StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();
 String DatoBluetooth = new String(data);// aqui se guarda el dato entrante dle bluetooth
 recDataString.append(arreglo);// la funcion que lo dividira
 sensor1 = recDataString.substring(0, 3);           //las divisiones de la cadena DatoBluetooth
 sensor2 = recDataString.substring(4, 8);           //las divisiones de la cadena DatoBluetooth
 sensor3 = recDataString.substring(9, 13);          //las divisiones de la cadena DatoBluetooth
```

Ahora luce así: Contenido de la cadena dividido en 3 partes

[image: Contenido de la cadena dividido en 3 partes]

Lo que necesito es que se guarde el contenido de cada columna "sensor" en un arreglo para cada uno.Mas  menos así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no, lo que vos necesitas es una clase que tenga 3 datos , y luego hagas un arreglo (o lista) con objetos de esa clase.. de esa forma te va a quedar ordenado.

Comment: Amigo, ya hiciste lo más difícil; crea la clase con tres datos y crea un array, o un arraylist de esa clase o algo para tener todos los sets de datos. Ya lo tienes casi todo hecho!

Comment: Si lo intente pero el problema es que me muestra error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10 y me muestra que el error es en for que uso para guardar los datos

Comment: Ya lo logré, gracias por su ayuda.